# Woocommerce API call back is not accepting POST parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, callback, woocommerce, http-post

I use the following code in one of my plugins

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_api_test_url', array( $this, 'test_url_callback' ) );
public function test_url_callback() {
    var_dump($_REQUEST);
}
```

this allows me to process data which is sent to
https://example.com/?wc-api=test_url

If I POST parameters to this url via GET method, I'll see them in the output, but if I use POST method for sending parameters, the output is empty.

So how can I process parameters which are sent via POST ?

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution for this?  The answer below did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('init', 'test_url_callback');
add_action('woocommerce_api_test_url', array( $this, 'test_url_callback' ) );
```

Please add `add_action('init', 'test_url_callback');` before your action then you can get POST parameters with $_POST in your test_url_callback function.

If parameters sent as json, you can get them with;

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```